# Setting JS Alt Store State For Testing Purposes

Tags: testing, reactjs, flux, alt.js

I want to test my store - check that the store's data changes correctly after an action.
I'm not able to change the state of the store that the action through the alt.dispatcher is connected to.

The [alt store test method](https://github.com/goatslacker/alt/blob/master/docs/testing/stores.md) doesn't work for me - I change the AltWrappedStore.state in my mocha test file, but the store's state that the action is connected to is different (it shows the default state).
How do I set a state of an alt store in order to test a change in the state (through an action)?

Answer (score 1):

Found it!
I'm using Alt's [bootstrap function](https://github.com/goatslacker/alt/blob/master/docs/bootstrap.md)
Just setting the store's state through that and that's it.